# create dynamic relationships between nodes in neo4j from csv file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi Have a CSV file and I want to create nodes and relationships simultaneously
   Im using below query to create nodes

```
using PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
load csv from "file:///home/gaurav/sharing/dataframe6.txt" as line fieldterminator" "
 MERGE (A :concept{name:line[0]})
 WITH line, A
 MERGE (B :concept{name:line[1]})
 WITH line, A, B
 create (A)-[:line[3]]->(B);  // This is trouble part
```

but when I try to create relationship between imported nodes then I get error

```
Invalid input '[': expected an identifier character, whitespace, '|', a length specification, a property map or ']' (line 7, column 18 (offset: 218))
"create (A)-[:line[3]]->(B);"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you truly want to create relationship in a dynamic fashion you need to use an APOC procedure, specifically `apoc.create.relationship`.

```
using PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
load csv from "file:///home/gaurav/sharing/dataframe6.txt" as line fieldterminator" "
MERGE (A :concept{name:line[0]})
WITH line, A
MERGE (B :concept{name:line[1]})
WITH line, A, B
CALL apoc.create.relationship(A, line[3], {}, B) YIELD rel
RETURN A,B,rel
```

Comment: Make sure to bring along the `line` variable in your last WITH.

Answer (score 0):

A relationship can not contain square brackets as its type name. You're trying to create a "line[3]" relationship between the nodes A and B.